# Practical uses of sparse matrices

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

Lately I've been working with matrices and I started learning about sparse matrices but I don't understand why they even exist. What are some practical uses of sparse matrices? If all they mainly hold are 0's do they have any useful functions?

Comment: You missed the point. They *don't* hold those 0's. Hence the savings.

Comment: They are useful since they conserve memory.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be related to any particular programming problem in C++ or Java, yet you added tags for those two languages. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Sparse matrices are generally just matrices with a lot of zero-entries (typically at least > 50%).

They can be represented in a very concise way, ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)) which can be used to do matrix operations (e.g. multiplication, transpose of a matrix, ...) in a fast and efficient way. Google Maps and other applications would be impossible without efficient sparse matrix algorithms.

If you want to dig deeper, I recommend [this website & professor](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/welcome.html), who developed some of those algorithms. Apparently, it's an ongoing research topic of high interest.

Answer (score 3):

I feel you're asking the question the other way around.

Sparse matrices are matrices with a high density of zeros.

Sparse matrices are very frequently encountered in many fields of scientific computing, and in veeery big sizes. It is not if they're useful, they just exist.

Now, the interesting and useful thing is how we represent them.

We tend to compress the sparse matrices to only take into account the non zero values and keep track of their location in the matrix.

This is useful ion a sense that it saves a lot of storage and the matrix operations are restricted to its non zero values.

Answer (score 2):

A field where sparse matrices are very common is solving discrete partial differential equations.

In a nutshell: you have a grid of voxels and the discretized differential equation states a relation between the quantity you are solving only for neighbouring voxels. The resulting matrix equation you need to solve typically has a band structure. In 2D the structure is even simpler and you have only values on the diagonal and one off the diagonal, all the other coefficients are zero.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 100k X 100k matrix.

If you want to store all of that using double precision in a 2D array you'll need 80Gbytes not counting any memory management overhead. If many of the elements are zero you can save a lot of memory.

For instance, if you have a regular sparse matrix such as a tridiagonal this can be stored in a 3 X 100k array with 2.4Mbytes. Implicitly all elements off the tridiagonal are zero.

As another example, in electronic circuit analysis matrices are used to solve a system of PDEs using the Newton-Raphson method. Since most circuit elements are connected to very few other ones the resulting matrix is sparse. This can be represented with a 2D linked list of non-zero elements. Again anything that isn't in the linked list is implicitly zero.